# Nested IF/AND statements in EXCEL with List criteria

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I understand nesting IF/AND statements but when my criteria is a list {} I'm not getting the desired results. Is there anyway to correct this without creating a "helper cell"?

```
=IF(AND(C2="CBHNP",F2="CHAM"),"CBHNP-Franklin Fulton",IF(AND(C2="CBHNP",F2<>"CHAM"),"CBHNP-Capital Region",IF(AND(C2="CCBH",F2={"RPSY","RDG","CSBERKS"}),"CCBH-Berks",IF(AND(C2="CCBH",F2={"YORK","YORK-P","CSYORK"}),"CCBH-YORK",IF(AND(C2="CCBH",F2<>{"YORK","YORK-P","CSYORK","RPSY","RDG","CSBERKS"}),"CCBH-North Central",B2)))))
```

Comment: Here's something to live by: If you find yourself nesting multiple `IFs`, make a table and use lookups instead

Comment: I like lookups but in this case I would have to use an Array since there are multiple criteria to be met at once. I need an if A and B then C and a lookup only give be and if A then B. An Index/Match I guess would have done the trick as well. Thanks for having me look at it from a different angel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Briefly: `AND(A1={1,2,3})`is always `False`, since it is the same as `AND(A1=1,A1=2,A1=3)`, and `A1` can only have 1 value at a time.

So, following the same principle, `AND(C2="CCBH",F2={"RPSY","RDG","CSBERKS"})` is also always `False`, because it is the same as writing `AND(C2="CCBH",F2="RPSY",F2="RDG",F2="CSBERKS")` and F2 can only have 1 value.  If you use an `OR` though... `AND(C2="CCBH",OR(F2={"RPSY","RDG","CSBERKS"}))` *can* be `True`, in the same way that `OR(A1={1,2,3})` can be.  It can also be re-written as `OR(AND(C2="CCBH",F2="RPSY"), AND(C2="CCBH",F2="RDG"), AND(C2="CCBH",F2="CSBERKS"))`

Thus:

```
=IF(AND(C2="CBHNP",F2="CHAM"),"CBHNP-Franklin Fulton",IF(AND(C2="CBHNP",F2<>"CHAM"),"CBHNP-Capital Region",IF(AND(C2="CCBH",OR(F2={"RPSY","RDG","CSBERKS"})),"CCBH-Berks",IF(AND(C2="CCBH",OR(F2={"YORK","YORK-P","CSYORK"})),"CCBH-YORK",IF(AND(C2="CCBH",F2<>{"YORK","YORK-P","CSYORK","RPSY","RDG","CSBERKS"}),"CCBH-North Central",B2)))))
```